# How to rebuild and restart the gae server for a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am looking for a way of how to rebuild and restart the gae server for a project 
to view it on `localhost` in the browser?

Comment: what do you mean by Rebuild and restart GAE server?

Comment: Do you want to programmatically start the local app server (e.g. in a post-unit-test hook) for your local testing purpose?

Comment: yeah I want to restart the local GAE server, cause I cannot see my changes in my project when I just refresh the browser...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the development server (dev_appserver.py in python, there's a Java equivalent but I don't the commandline).  It comes with the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

To clean the localhost datastore, remove the `appengine-generated` under war directory